# Filter overlapping entries in bed file

Tags: bash, shell, bioinformatics, bed, bedtools

I have a bed file that looks like this:

```
1   183113  183114  chr1:183113-183240  0   +
1   187286  187287  chr1:187128-187287  0   -
1   187576  187587  chr1:187375-187577  0   -
1   187580  187590  chr1:187379-187577  0   -
```

My aim is to extract only those rows for which entries do not overlap with any others. For some time I have been trying *bedtools merge* according to the [doc](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/merge.html). I wanted to use specific flags to count the entries that constituted to each "merged" fragment and later keep only those with value "1" but here comes the problem: I don't know how to keep the information about the strand, score (this should always be 0) and name(this might be reconstructed from first 3 columns).
Does anyone know how to put these things together?

Output should look exactly as input (above) bed but only with these rows that do not overlap with anything else.

```
1   183113  183114  chr1:183113-183240  0   +
1   187286  187287  chr1:187128-187287  0   -
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the desired output.

Comment: @agc : edited post - output is in the same format

Comment: Clarification:  please include a sample of the desired input and output that are not identical.  They can have the same format, but must not have entirely the same data.

Comment: I think you need `reduce` from [GenomicRanges package](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.pdf).

Comment: Could this work (using the right options): `bedtools merge`, then `bedtools complement` on the result, then `bedtools intersect` of the original with the complement of the merge ?

Comment: @agc - I have changed the Input and added desired output.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I worked this out:

1) Count the overlaps in the original input

```
bedtools merge -i IN.bed -c 1 -o count > counted
```

2) Filter out only those rows that do not overlap with anything

```
awk '/\t1$/{print}' counted > filtered
```

3) Intersect it with the original input and keep only those original rows that were found after filtering as well

```
bedtools intersect -a IN.bed -b filtered -wa > OUT.bed
```